# Gradle : TaskExecutionGraph.beforeTask and afterTask are deprecated. How to substitute them?

Tags: android, gradle

```
afterEvaluate {
    gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
}}
```

here, beforeTask is deprecated and no google search shows any results of how to substitute this with the right option

Answer (score 0):

I see that `whenReady()` is not deprecated. What if you do the following?

```
afterEvaluate {
  gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { TaskExecutionGraph taskExecutionGraph ->
    taskExecutionGraph.getAllTasks().each { Task task -> task.doFirst { ... } }
  }
}
```

I did not try to compile this, so there may be errors, but the concept is valid based on the API documents.